# Using Borland C++ Code in VC++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, borland-c++

Is there a way to access Borland output in VC++, for method calls and other stuff?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please clarify your question?  Do you want to see debugging or tracing information for a Borland C++ program in VC++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My info may be (way) outdated, but what I had to before was to make sure that Borland output a COFF format OBJ or LIB file to link with VC.

The other option is to have Borland output a DLL, and then use that from VC++. Name mangling and calling conventions may cause a pain. I honestly haven't used a Borland compiler in half a decade(even though I used to work there, a decade and half ago), so I'm not sure if a LIB for a Borland compiled DLL will link nicely with VC++.

If all else fails, compile a DLL with the Borland compiler, use Dumpbin to find the exports, then LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress to get the function pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Create a static library, then link it into VC++ project. Be careful with calling conventions.